# Why is visual studio 2010 looking for __thiscall rather than __cdecl calling conventions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, linker, calling-convention

Overall I am trying to link an opencv test program with the opencv libraries I compiled using 64-bit visual studio 2010 professional. An example error is:

```
1>webcamtest.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::VideoCapture::isOpened(void)const " (?isOpened@VideoCapture@cv@@UBE_NXZ)
```

The question is why __thiscall, when opencv_highui249.dll which it is linked with contains

```
Symbol name  : ?isOpened@VideoWriter@cv@@UEBA_NXZ (public: virtual bool __cdecl cv::VideoWriter::isOpened(void)const )
```

__cdecl makes sense, which suggests that the library is built correctly.
When linking the test program, opencv_highui249.dll is being searched, so the build flags appear to be correct, but apparently I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you used x64 libraries?
Microsoft reduced the calling conventions in x64. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx). Basically everything is now `__fastcall`.
The compiler can still use `__thiscall` but it is ignored([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw.aspx)). So your test program is fine but your library looks wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`__thiscall` is the default calling convention in VS for member functions of classes.  Perhaps the header files are missing the `__cdecl` specifier, or the compile flags are incorrectly set so a relevant #define for it isn't being set.

Answer (score 0):

`__thiscall` is the default for class member functions in MSVC, you either need to compile OpenCV with the same settings, or explicitly use `__cdecl` in the header definitions.